# A possible PHP bug with date_default_timezone_set and date?

Tags: php, date

Suppose this code:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$time = gmmktime(14, 50, 0, 5, 12, 2013);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s O', $time).'<br />';
echo gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s O', $time).'<br />';

date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
$time = gmmktime(14, 50, 0, 5, 12, 2013);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s O', $time).'<br />';
echo gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s O', $time);
?>
```

On my local server I get the output:

```
2013-05-12 14:50:00 +0000
2013-05-12 14:50:00 +0000
2013-05-12 14:50:00 +0000
2013-05-12 14:50:00 +0000
```

But on production the same code produces:

```
2013-05-12 10:50:00 -0400
2013-05-12 14:50:00 +0000
2013-05-12 14:50:00 +0000
2013-05-12 14:50:00 +0000
```

Changing time of the machine doesn't affect the output in any way.

Some info:

```
$ date +%Z
GMT
$ date +%z
+0000
```

- PHP 5.3.25 (cli) (built: May 11 2013 09:54:00)
- CentOS release 5.9 (Final)

Comment: Any PHP notices or warnings in your server logs?

Comment: @Jocelyn He is not encountering any errors or warnings, it's `-0400` what changes

Comment: @Mr.Alien I have already read the question. You can't know whether there is something in the error log or not.

Comment: What happens if you set the time zone to GMT? Theoretically, they should be the same, but UTC itself (unlike e.g. UTC(0)) can be ambiguous.

Comment: What output do you get from `date_default_timezone_get()`?

Comment: Setting it to GMT works. How come?

Comment: Don't know. It seems that `date_default_timezone_set` is a little buggy with 'UTC' according to the internet

Comment: Please run the commands "date +%Z" and "date +%z" on your prod server and tell us the output.

Comment: And also just "date" compared to your local server.

Comment: Do you have the same php version on both local and production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phpinfo() showed "Olson" Timezone Database Version as 0.system, so I used the command

```
pecl upgrade timezonedb
```

and added

```
extension=timezonedb.so
```

to php.ini

After restarting the server, the problem has been resolved with the new timezone DB version 2013.3

Answer (score 0):

Might be it's not about code ..

If "O" is Difference to Greenwich time (GMT) in hours .. maybe time setting in the production computer is not set correctly ..